# Trouble installing Clojure dev environment on ubuntu

Tags: configuration, emacs, clojure

I followed this guide:

http://wiki.unto.net/setting-up-clojure-and-slime

Which walked me through the steps of building Clojure and Clojure-contrib from source along with SLIME and swank emacs scripts. I am a total noob when it comes to emacs.

I am getting this error:

> File error: Cannot open load file, swank-clojure-autoload

This is my .emacs:

```
;; Clojure
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/git/clojure-mode")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/git/swank-clojure/src/emacs")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/git/slime")

(setq swank-clojure-jar-path "~/git/clojure/clojure-1.2.0-master-SNAPSHOT.jar")

;; clojure-contrib, when compiled as above, is not working at the moment
;; (setq swank-clojure-extra-classpaths
;;      (list "~/git/clojure-contrib/clojure-contrib.jar"))

(require 'clojure-mode)
(require 'swank-clojure-autoload)
(require 'slime)

(eval-after-load "slime" (slime-setup '(slime-repl)))
(slime-setup)
```

I also encountered this same error while following the steps to [this guide](http://riddell.us/ClojureWithEmacsSlimeSwankOnUbuntu.html) on a separate install.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the error is caused because the swank-clojure git repo does not have swank-clojure-autoload or even the directory src/emacs in it.

I would recommend installing swank-clojure and slime using elpa instead.

See here for instructions on getting elpa up and running: http://tromey.com/elpa/install.html

once you've done that then M-x package-install swank-clojure should get you up and running.